# What is the correct way to compile multiple test sources with Catch2?

Tags: c++, catch2

I have the following project structure:

**test_main.cc**

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN

#include "catch2.hpp"
```

**test1.cc**

```
#include "catch2.hpp"
#include "test_utils.hpp"

TEST_CASE("test1", "[test1]") {
  REQUIRE(1 == 1);
}
```

**test2.cc**

```
#include "catch2.hpp"
#include "test_utils.hpp"

TEST_CASE("test2", "[test2]") {
  REQUIRE(2 == 2);
}
```

**test_utils.hpp**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

void something_great() {
  std::cout << ":)\n";
}
```

If I compile using something like `clang++ -std=c++17 test_main.cc test1.cc test2.cc`, the function `something_great` is defined in both test1.o and test2.o. This leads to an error like

```
duplicate symbol __Z15something_greatv in:
    test1.cc.o
    test2.cc.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

In the [Scaling Up](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/master/docs/tutorial.md#scaling-up) section of the Catch2 documentation, they mention that in order to split up your tests you may want to

> Use as many additional cpp files (or whatever you call your
>   implementation files) as you need for your tests, partitioned however
>   makes most sense for your way of working. Each additional file need
>   only #include "catch.hpp"

but in the [examples section of the documentation](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/tree/master/examples) I don't see a use case like mine. I read [this blog post](https://chunminchang.github.io/blog/post/how-to-avoid-duplicate-symbols-when-compiling) which describes three solutions which don't appeal to me: defining functions as macros, or making functions `static` or `inline`.

**Is there another way to compile these files which yield a single executable with the main function defined by `test_main.cc`?**

Comment: Add inline here. `inline void something_great() {`. This is the duplicate symbol problem. Everything else is good. Or move it to a `test_utils.cc` and only have declaration in header.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This actually has nothing to do with Catch or testing. When you `#include` a file in C++, it gets copy-pasted at the `#include` line verbatim. If you put free function definitions in headers, you would see this problem building your actual program, etc.

The underlying problem is that `#include` is not the same kind of import-a-module directive as is the equivalent directive (`import`, `require`, etc.) in most languages, which do the sane thing in a situation like this (confirm that the header is the same one we've already seen and ignore the repeated method definition).

The commenter that suggested you write `inline` is technically correct, in the sense that this will "solve your problem" because your compiler won't generate object code for the method multiple times. However, it doesn't really explain what's going on or address the underlying issue.

---

The clean solution is:

- In `test_utils.hpp`, replace the method definition with a method *declaration*: `void something_great();`.
- Create `test_utils.cc` with the definition of the method (which you currently have in the `.hpp`).
- `clang++ -std=c++17 test1.cc -c`
- `clang++ -std=c++17 test2.cc -c`
- `clang++ -std=c++17 test_main.cc -c`
- `clang++ -std=c++17 test_utils.cc -c`
- `clang++ -std=c++17 test1.o test2.o test_utils.o test_main.o`

I also recommend you read this: [What is the difference between a definition and a declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration)

Explicitly:

```
// test_utils.hpp
#pragma once

// This tells the compiler that when the final executable is linked,
// there will be a method named something_great which takes no arguments
// and returns void defined; the definition lives in test_utils.o in our
// case, although in practice the definition could live in any .o file
// in the final linking clang++ call.
void something_great();
```

And:

```
// test_utils.cpp
#include "test_utils.hpp"
#include <iostream>

// Generates a DEFINITION for something_great, which
// will get put in test_utils.o.
void something_great() { std::cout << "Hi\n"; }
```

---

It seems you are worried about "recompiling Catch" every time you make a change to a test. I hate to break it to you, but you are in C++ land now: you are going to be recompiling stuff pointlessly a lot. Header-only libraries like Catch MUST be "recompiled" to some extent when a source file including them changes, because for better or worse, if the source file or a header file included transitively from the source file includes `catch2.hpp`, then the source code of `catch2.hpp` will get parsed by the compiler when that source file is read.

Comment: Since this correct answer was posted, several compilers have implemented C++20's modules, which should make OP's requirements achievable.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation, I found a reasonable solution which doesn't require you to fully recompile Catch any time you make a change to a test.

Define **test_main.cc** in the same way as before:

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN

#include "catch2.hpp"
```

Add another .cc file, **test_root** which includes your test files as headers:

```
#include "test1.hpp"
#include "test2.hpp"
```

Change your test sources to headers:

**test1.hpp**

```
#pragma once
#include "catch2.hpp"
#include "test_utils.hpp"

TEST_CASE("test1", "[test1]") {
  REQUIRE(1 == 1);
}
```

**test2.hpp**

```
#pragma once
#include "catch2.hpp"
#include "test_utils.hpp"

TEST_CASE("test2", "[test2]") {
  REQUIRE(2 == 2);
}
```

Compile separately

```
clang++ -std=c++17 test_main.cc -c
clang++ -std=c++17 test_root.cc -c
clang++ test_main.o test_root.o
```

Where test_main.cc needs only be compiled once. test_root.cc will need to be recompiled whenever you change your tests and of course you must relink the two object files.

I will leave this answer unaccepted for now in case there are better solutions.

Comment: I'm curious why this was downvoted. Was there something "wrong" with this approach?

Comment: maybe because the catch2 tutorial says that you should not write your tests in header files: https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/master/docs/tutorial.md#scaling-up

Comment: The current documentation has no *"Scaling up"* portion there. Does that mean it is okay now for Catch2 v3.x?